# prefetch_related() ForeignKey reverse lookup in Django?

Tags: django, orm, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I've got two models:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    ...

class Supplier(models.Model):
  company = models.ForeignKey(Company, null=True, related_name="suppliers")
```

How to get all Companies with their related Suppliers?

I've tried:

```
Company.objects.prefetch_related('suppliers') 
Company.objects.prefetch_related('supplier_set') 
Company.objects.prefetch_related('suppliers').all()
...
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

[`prefetch_related` just adds the SQL query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to get the suppliers so that when you do `company.suppliers.all()` you don't incur another SQL hit on top of `Company.objects.all()`. You can access the suppliers normally thereafter:

```
companies = Company.objects.all().prefetch_related('suppliers')

for company in companies:
    # Does not require a new SQL query
    suppliers = company.suppliers.all()
```

Comment: Any way to include additional SQL query? I need to fetch companies with suppliers to use it in templates after. Tried `select_related('suppliers')`, however I get: `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'suppliers'. Choices are: (none)`

Comment: Huh, that's a separate issue. You're using `select_related` on `Company`? Do you still have `related_name='suppliers'` on the `Supplier` model?